# How to check condition before starting Databricks workflows jobs?

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

[image]

I already have my pipelines ready in Databricks workflows but based on few condition check on input data I have to decide which path of the pipeline I have to execute. Is there any service/technique  available in Databricks workflows using which I can perform pre specified condition check and decide which path to execute?

Note - Running databricks in Azure but requirement is I have to explore possible ways to make this pipeline as much databricks native as possible and cannot use data factory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **If/else condition** tasks and **taskValues** to achieve this.

With the help of a Python notebook, you can set task values that can be shared among the workflow's tasks.

Create a Python notebook that checks the condition based on your data, then use **dbutils** to set the task values.

Example code:

```py
base_pipeline=True

if base_pipeline:
    dbutils.jobs.taskValues.set(key = 'Start_base_pipeline', value = True)
else:
    dbutils.jobs.taskValues.set(key = 'Start_base_pipeline', value = False)
```

This sets the task value named `Start_base_pipeline`, which can be accessed in other workflow tasks.

Refer to the following documentation for more information about task values:

[Share information between tasks in a Databricks job](https://docs.databricks.com/en/workflows/jobs/share-task-context.html#share-information-between-tasks-in-a-databricks-job)

Next, create an **If/else condition** task that checks this task value and triggers your pipeline accordingly.

[image]

and

[image]

Retrieve the task value using a dynamic expression like this:

`{{tasks.[task_name].values.[value_name]}}`

In this case, it's `{{tasks.Check_pipeline.values.Start_base_pipeline}}`

Learn more about dynamic values by clicking **Browse dynamic values**.

Next, add tasks for **True** and **False** conditions.

Since you mentioned you have base and incremental pipelines, you need to add tasks of type **Run job** and select your base and incremental job accordingly in the **If/else condition** task.

Below is the full pipeline.

[image]

Output:

[image]